# Two Factor Google Authentication not matching the codes on the server- ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, validation, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I am using the below code in two factor authentication which uses google authenticator.
The problem with this validation, is that google authenticator code is validating correctly on my local machine, but not on the server.
The server time setting is : (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
My system time setting is : (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)

On server-when i try to hit validate button multiple times, it sometimes validates correctly sometimes not. I am not sure why its doing this.

Anybody can help me giving idea/suggestion to sort this issue

```
 public static class TimeBasedOneTimePassword
    {
        public static readonly DateTime UNIX_EPOCH = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        private static MemoryCache _cache;

        static TimeBasedOneTimePassword()
        {
          _cache = new MemoryCache("TimeBasedOneTimePassword");
        }

        public static string GetPassword(string secret)
        {
          return GetPassword(secret, GetCurrentCounter());
        }

        public static string GetPassword(string secret, DateTime epoch, int timeStep)
        {
          long counter = GetCurrentCounter(DateTime.UtcNow, epoch, timeStep);
          return GetPassword(secret, counter);
        }

        public static string GetPassword(string secret, DateTime now, DateTime epoch, int timeStep, int digits)
        {
          long counter = GetCurrentCounter(now, epoch, timeStep);
          return GetPassword(secret, counter, digits);
        }

        private static string GetPassword(string secret, long counter, int digits = 6)
        {
          return HashedOneTimePassword.GeneratePassword(secret, counter, digits);
        }

        private static long GetCurrentCounter()
        {
          return GetCurrentCounter(DateTime.UtcNow, UNIX_EPOCH, 30);
        }

        public static long GetCurrentRemaining()
        {
          return (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - UNIX_EPOCH).TotalSeconds % 30;
        }


        private static long GetCurrentCounter(DateTime now, DateTime epoch, int timeStep)
        {
          return (long)(now - epoch).TotalSeconds / timeStep;
        }

        public static bool IsValid(string secret, string password, int checkAdjacentIntervals = 1)
        {
          if (password == GetPassword(secret))
            return true;

          for (int i = 1; i <= checkAdjacentIntervals; i++)
          {
             if (password == GetPassword(secret, GetCurrentCounter() + i))
                return true;

             if (password == GetPassword(secret, GetCurrentCounter() - i))
                return true;
          }

          return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I removed my previous comment of never checking the base `GetPassword(secret)` I see now it's prior to the for loop, I had missed that previously :)  Have you tried with a higher check adjacent interval?

Comment: i did try to put 10 for checkAdjacentIntervals , but when i do that its even authenticating successfully the past code,means the code keeps changing for every 30sec, so the past 30 secs code is also getting validated successfully. I am not sure if it is a correct way of doing it, since its a two factor auth and we are doing extra validation for security purpose only.

Comment: indeed, but I think that's the purpose of the checkAdjacentIntervals - to account for small time discrepancies between client and server.  You could probably narrow it down to less than 10, but 1 might not be enough.  This dual factor authentication method (without checking adjacent intervals) would require both client and server to have the same understanding of time... at all time... within a 30 second margin of error.  That seems like it would be pretty difficult to pull off.

Comment: Thanks @Kritner. I heard about NTP which can be used to sync time. Are you aware of about how to it on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did try to set checkAdjacentIntervals to 5,i was able to validate the google authenticator code , but as mentioned earlier, it validates the past codes which is not right in my case.

So we have corrected the server's time by synchronizing it correctly using NTP , then it started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it may help others like me who come looking for an answer. Google Authentication works based on time. API would validate the codes that were generated recently in the past based on time (mark it, it is time, not the time-zone). So, if actual time of your system is not in synch with the device on which you are generating the codes, the issue would occur. Especially, when time of the system is behind the time of the device. If you want to validate my answer, try entering some older codes (based on the tie gap between the system and the device). checkAdjacentIntervals would help you when your system is ahead of the device, but not when it is behind.